# Meteor.connect throwing error in React Native (Version 0.61.5)

Tags: meteor, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo, react-native-meteor

I'm using [react-native-meteor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-meteor) module in **react-native-app** to connect it to [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) server.
On Calling the following function in App.js ,

```
Meteor.connect('ws://192.168.x.x:3000/websocket');
```

I was getting this error

```
Invariant Violation: NetInfo has been removed from React.Native.It can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-netinfo'
```

An issue is already opened here [NetInfo Issue](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor/issues/342) but not resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

NetInfo has been removed from react-native core. It should be installed as a stand alone dependency using following command:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/netinfo
or:
npm install --save @react-native-community/netinfo
```

step by step instructions can be found on this [github link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo)

I followed these steps mentioned on the above mentioned link , but it didn't resolve the issue completely. After digging the issue a little bit, I found out that in **node_modules/react-native-meteor/src/Meteor.js** ,
They are still importing NetInfo from 'react-native' and using the **old functions**

```
import { Platform, View, NetInfo } from 'react-native'; 
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(
  (connected )  => {
  if(connected)
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', isConnected => {
    if (isConnected && Data.ddp.autoReconnect) {
      Data.ddp.connect();
    }
  });
}
);
```

**which is obsoleted now.**

It has to be imported from **@react-native-community/netinfo** 
After doing the following changes in **node_modules/react-native-meteor/src/Meteor.js** .
Error fixed:

```
import { Platform, View } from 'react-native';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
  let isConnected = state.isConnected;
   if(isConnected)
        NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', isConnected => {
        if (isConnected && Data.ddp.autoReconnect) {
          Data.ddp.connect();
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ImFarhad Does that still work for you? Using your changes to meteor.js I get the error "RNCNetInfo.getCurrentState got 3 arguments, expected 2". Do you know a way around this?

Comment: yup, It's working for me. have u followed all the instructions given at this Link
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo (mentioned in the answer above).

Comment: I'm using expo and I can't find my "android/build.gradle" file. Do you happen to know how to get around that?

Comment: @HaakonFlaar Did you have any luck figuring this out? I'm having the same issue. I'm not seeing anywhere in the source code where 3 arguments are expected.